# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php

Al momento de querer actualizar información me salen estos errores, solo que no entiendo muy bien

> "Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function ControladorGeneral::ctrlUpdateProfesor(), 1 passed in
>   D:\AppServ\www\mvc-sacapi\backoffice\ajax\process.php on line 155 and
>   exactly 15 expected in
>   D:\AppServ\www\mvc-sacapi\backoffice\controladores\general.controlador.php:109
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\AppServ\www\mvc-sacapi\backoffice\ajax\process.php(155):
>   ControladorGeneral::ctrlUpdateProfesor(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   D:\AppServ\www\mvc-sacapi\backoffice\controladores\general.controlador.php
>   on line 109"

```
static public function ctrlUpdateProfesor(
    $tabla, 
    $numControl, 
    $nombre,
    $apellidoPaterno,
    $apellidoMaterno,
    $password,
    $email,
    $foto,
    $permisoAcceso,
    $SubPermisoAcceso,
    $idFacultad1,
    $idFacultad2,
    $idFacultad3,
    $idFacultad4,
    $url
){
    $res = ModeloGeneral::mdlUpdateProfesor(
        $tabla, 
        $numControl, 
        $nombre,
        $apellidoPaterno,
        $apellidoMaterno,
        $password,
        $email,
        $foto,
        $permisoAcceso,
        $SubPermisoAcceso,
        $idFacultad1,
        $idFacultad2,
        $idFacultad3,
        $idFacultad4
    );
    if($res == "success"){
        echo '<script>window.location = "'.ControladorGeneral::ctrRutaBackoffice().''.$url.'/exitop";</script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script>window.location = "'.ControladorGeneral::ctrRutaBackoffice().''.$url.'/error";</script>';
    }
}


        }else if ($_REQUEST["tipo"] == "profesores"){
        $data = array(
            "numC"      => $_REQUEST["num_c"],
            "nombre"    => $_REQUEST["nombreu"],
            "apellidop" => $_REQUEST["apellidop"],
            "apellidom" => $_REQUEST["apellidom"],
            "email"     => $_REQUEST["email"],
            "permisoAcceso" => $_REQUEST["permisos_acceso"],
            "subPermisosAcceso" => $_REQUEST["sub_permiso_acceso"],
            "password"  => $_REQUEST["password"],
            "idFacultad1" => $_REQUEST['1'],
            "idFacultad2" => $_REQUEST['2'],
            "idFacultad3" => $_REQUEST['3'],
            "idFacultad4" => $_REQUEST['4'],
            "url" => $_REQUEST['url'],
            "foto" => "user-default.png"
        );

        switch($_REQUEST["value"]){
            case "add":  $query -> ctrlAgregarProfesor($data); break;
            case "edit": $query -> ctrlUpdateProfesor($data); break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Deberías compartir la línea 109 del archivo `general.controlador.php` para saber cómo llamas a `ctrlUpdateProfesor()` y así ayudarte a hacerlo correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Tu método llamado `ctrlUpdateProfesor` en su declaración tiene al menos 15 parámetros.

Sin embargo cuando la invocas solo recibe 1 argumento que es el array de valores.

Si la idea es que vas a mandar los datos dentro de un array enotnces tu método debería estar asi:

```
static public function ctrlUpdateProfesor($valores = array())
{
     ..............
}
```

Posterior tienes la declaración de tus valores:

```
$data = array(
            "numC"      => $_REQUEST["num_c"],
            "nombre"    => $_REQUEST["nombreu"],
            "apellidop" => $_REQUEST["apellidop"],
            "apellidom" => $_REQUEST["apellidom"],
            "email"     => $_REQUEST["email"],
            "permisoAcceso" => $_REQUEST["permisos_acceso"],
            "subPermisosAcceso" => $_REQUEST["sub_permiso_acceso"],
            "password"  => $_REQUEST["password"],
            "idFacultad1" => $_REQUEST['1'],
            "idFacultad2" => $_REQUEST['2'],
            "idFacultad3" => $_REQUEST['3'],
            "idFacultad4" => $_REQUEST['4'],
            "url" => $_REQUEST['url'],
            "foto" => "user-default.png"
        );
```

Y finalmente cuando invoques a la función:

```
case "add":  $query -> ctrlAgregarProfesor($data); break;
```

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
function foo($data = array())
{
    var_dump($data);
}

$datos = array(1,2,3,4,5);

foo($datos);
```

Que imprime:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(3)
  [3]=>
  int(4)
  [4]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda